# ElasticSearch-composite IndexReaders cannot exceed 2147483647

Tags: elasticsearch

Getting following exception from one of the shard in ES Index,

[Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[fw][4] failed recovery]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Too many documents, composite IndexReaders cannot exceed 2147483647]; ]]

Please somebody help.

Comment: This value is the integer maximum value.  The message talks of GatewayRecovery. It seems that you have a problem during the recovery phase. How many docs do you have?

Comment: it reached more than 3 billion on my 5 shard cluster. cant we store more than 2147483647 docs per shard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed through another post, we cannot store more than 2147483647 docs per shard.This is the inernal limit of the lucene index 4.x.

Comment: Do you (or anyone else) know if this limit has been increased for more recent versions of lucene?